# How to get Declined reason from Docusing envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

i try to get Declined reason from envelopesApi, but cant get details, but when i get voided reason, i can retrieve from envelopesApi using AccessToken and EnvelopeID, Please guide me how to get declined details from envelopesApi ?

Here the code i used to retrieve void reason,

```
            Dim apiClient = New ApiClient(Accesstoken(3) & ":" & Accesstoken(4))
            apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & Accesstoken(1))
            Dim envelopesApi = New EnvelopesApi(apiClient)
           
            Dim results As Envelope = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(Accesstoken(2), EnvelopID)

            Dim status As String = results.Status.ToString
            Dim strReason As String = ""


            If status = "sent" Then
                strReason = ""
            ElseIf status = "completed" Then
                strReason = ""
            ElseIf status = "voided" Then
                strReason = results.VoidedReason.ToString()

            ElseIf status = "declined" Then
               ' strReason = results.VoidedReason.ToString()  ' Here i want to get declined reason
            End If
```

Thanks and Regards
Aravind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decline is associated with a specific recipient, so you have to retrieve the list of recipients.

Instead of `envelopesApi.GetEnvelope()` call `envelopesApi.ListRecipients()`

Inside the `Recipient` object you'll find a property called `DeclinedReason`